# Using Curl to push build to Linux/Hadoop environment with SCP protocol result in stale build delivered

Tags: linux, hadoop, curl, scp

This is an interesting issue that I couldn't identify the cause is from `Curl`, or `SCP` or `Linux`/`Hadoop`.

Current environment has following command to push a build to Linux/Hadoop environment.

```
curl -k -v scp://this.is.a.fake.url.com/linux/mount/drive/to/hadoop my-build.app
```

After providing the correct username and password, the build pushed successfully.

However when I check content of the build, it is a file from previous release (an old version that was uploaded before). It almost feels like there is buffer mechanism either by Curl or linux/hadoop to keep old build (which must be stored somewhere)

I also found an interesting observation that if I **delete** existing build in Hadoop/Linux before the CURL command, the issue never occur again. So the problem is when using Curl to upload and **replace** existing file, make fresh upload without existing file is always successful

Just wondering anyone had the similar experience.

Comment: wait, how does hadoop factor in?  does this curl/scp somehow end up in HDFS?

Comment: @Matt Andruff, that is correct, file eventually transfer to linux directory but also a mount drive/point to Hadoop HDFS environment. I am scratching my head for all possible causes so just want to bring every factors. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Please clarify how you are mounting HDFS to a local filesystem device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, HDFS files are read only.  You don't modify files, you either append, or replace --> (create new, Delete old, rename to the same file name.)  This is consistent with what you are seeing, and likely there is a lost error message in your mount tooling. (As it's not possible to modify it must be silently failing)